# How to check the desired state file in K8s

Tags: kubernetes

I'm sorry for the noob question.

Is there a way to check the kubernetes desired state file?

I'm looking for something similar to `terraform state list` that exists in Terraform.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be this is not direct answer though you can try kubernetes API's, all services/resources collectively can be considered as state. With this you can get current health as well as dump the definition of all services/resources etc.

[K8s Health Checks](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/using-api/health-checks/)

K8s keeping metadata in etcd but we can't say it's state file directly, even to get correct details you need to prepare cluster in advance.